# How to add custom Flake8 rules?

Tags: python, flake8

Is there any way to add custom rules to flake8?

There are bunch of rules here https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/ but I can't find the rules' source code in flake8's git repo.

I want to write a custom rule.

Comment: I think you need to write your own Flake8 plugin: https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/plugin-development/

Comment: It seems I can write plugin. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write your own Flake8 plugin.

From the Flake8's docs:

> Flake8 is useful on its own but a lot of Flake8’s popularity is due to its extensibility. Our community has developed plugins that augment Flake8’s behaviour. Most of these plugins are uploaded to PyPI. **The developers of these plugins often have some style they wish to enforce**.

You can't exactly add custom rules to Flake8 itself, apart from submitting a feature-request and hoping it gets accepted. But it allows you to publish a plugin that can be installed *in addition* to Flake8, and Flake8 can then find it and use it along with its own built-in checks.

They have nice developer documentation on how to write one: [Writing Plugins for Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/plugin-development/index.html). If it's a custom rule that you want checked, then it's probably a [Check Plugin](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/plugin-development/plugin-parameters.html). It receives the same info about the code as its built-in checkers does, then you need to write your own code for checking the lines.

You can also check out the source codes of existing [Flake8 plugins](https://pypi.org/search/?q=flake8-*) for inspiration, such as:

- [flake8-quotes](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-quotes/) ([source](https://github.com/zheller/flake8-quotes/tree/master/flake8_quotes))
- [flake8-return](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-return/) ([source](https://github.com/afonasev/flake8-return/tree/master/flake8_return))